# Files not downloadable via Browser but with Wget. Why?

Tags: browser, download, wget

Recently I came across an issue on a client machine where the machine was not able to download some files. We tried to download the files via Browser, but it did not generate any response. However, the files are downloadable via WGet. Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: Some browser extension or virsu scanner may interfere. Or the server does not like the browser's user string (or cookies or ...). Do you have access to the server and/or its log files?

Comment: I am afraid not. The server is hosted on the internet . I cannot access its log files